# How did this programmer achieve this calculator inside of a game?

Tags: algorithm, calculator

Link here: [YouTube Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZiRgYBHoAoU)

I'm curious and thinking for a long time now I have **no idea** how this man pulled it off. I just see levers and thread going and coming into cogs at random so it seems.

Can someone shed some light for us curious geeks. :)

Comment: What does this have to do with programming?

Comment: He made something in a game using an algorithm. While it's not code per-se it is relevant to this website. I don't know why 3 people want it closed when 'algorithm' tagged questions are allowed.

Comment: This looks like a valid, programming-related question to me. Voted to reopen.

Comment: Did he use *programming* to make it?  What language?

Comment: I'll give the benefit of the doubt on this one and vote to reopen.

Comment: @WhirlWind: he seems to have programmed the calculator by simulating low-tech electronic components. So in a way, the game itself is a programming environment.

Comment: How is the implementation of an 8-bit adder *not programming related*? Is only jQuery and django allowed here?

Comment: @Mauricio well, if it's Turing-complete, it's programming. ;)

Comment: Someone [made a computer](http://www.bay12forums.com/smf/index.php?topic=49641.0) in the [Dwarf Fortress](http://www.bay12games.com/dwarves/) game, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He seems to have programmed the calculator by simulating gates using in-game mechanisms (I'm kind of rusty on this topic but see [this](http://ibiblio.org/kuphaldt/electricCircuits/Digital/DIGI_9.html) for reference). So in a way, the game itself is somewhat of a hardware simulator in this case.

Comment: +1 this is how it was done.  Note that an [8-bit adder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adder_%28electronics%29) has several hundred gates.  Impressive!

Answer (score 1):

d03boy: Little Big Planet allows players to design their own levels, essentially programming the game environment with in-game objects that simulate physical ones.

To answer the question, it looks to me like the level designer created a virtual [adding machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adding_machine) using in-game objects.  Pretty neat, if you ask me.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I think the original question should have provided some of that highly relevant information within